# Add json data to datatables

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I am trying to populate datatables with a complex json scheme, however I don't know exactly how to do it.

- First, some parts of json are nested and it needs iteration.
- Second I need to create some markup, basically a href link.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#empTable').DataTable({
      'processing': true,
      'serverSide': true,
      'serverMethod': 'post',

      'ajax': {
          'url':'/dashboard/ajaxgetrequests',
          dataSrc: "json_list"
      },
      'columns': [
         { data: 'firstname' },
         { data: 'funding_project_name' } // this must be a link like <a href='/<relation_id>'><funding_project_name></a>
      ]
   });
});
```

---

```
{  
   "json_list":{  
      "125":{  
         "firstname":"John",
         "funding_project_name":"A",
         "relation_id": "7"

      },
      "133":{  
         "firstname":"Cesar",
         "funding_project_name":[  
            "A",
            "B"
         ],
         "relation_id":[  
            "7",
            "9"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you can use the [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) utility, you can use a function for every column as needed

Answer (score 0):

1) For nested JSON you can use something like this:

```
// JSON structure for each row:
//   {
//      "engine": {value},
//      "browser": {value},
//      "platform": {
//         "inner": {value}
//      },
//      "details": [
//         {value}, {value}
//      ]
//   }
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajaxSource": "sources/deep.txt",
  "columns": [
    { "data": "engine" },
    { "data": "browser" },
    { "data": "platform.inner" },
    { "data": "details.0" },
    { "data": "details.1" }
  ]
} );
```

2) To edit and insert a link you can use `columns.render` ([documentation](http://columns.render%60https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render))

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
    }
  } ]
} );
```

Comment: this can be helpful, but does not reproduce the json structure provided.

Comment: I gave you a solution for two problems with datatable. Edit a general solution according your needs

Comment: Do you know how many "funding_project_name" you have? Maximum 2 as in your example or even more?

Comment: No limit. My problem is to parse a specific json structure like the one in the question.

Comment: I am thinking that, can you parse the JSON directly in the server? You can collapse the dynamic fields of JSON  in always one field so you have a fixed JSON structure? Then, in render column you create your custom column with custom column..

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, there may be a better built in way of handling this but when I experience things that do not fit the exact mold of using the base datatable functionality, I prefer to take manual control of the generation. This will give you an overview on how to do it with your structure:

Just basic html for your table (nothing really to see here):

```
<table id="empTable">
<thead>
  <tr><th>First Name</th><th>ProjectName</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

In JS we declare a variable we can use throughout our script then on ready event we instatiate our datatable:

```
var dt;

$(document).ready(function () {
  dt = $('#empTable').DataTable();
  loadDT();
});
```

We will also use a function call 'loadDT()' and what this will do is trigger a ajax call to the backend to get your json, in this example, I'm just gonna mock it but in your world so this on the ajax success:

Iterate your list and determine the types then use the api call row.add to dynamically add new rows to your table. (notice we are reusing the stored variable dt that we initially declared.) This is where you can do whatever custom logic fun you need to do.

```
function loadDT(){
  var mockJSON = { "json_list":{  "125":{  "firstname":"John","funding_project_name":"A","relation_id": "7"},"133":{  "firstname":"Cesar","funding_project_name":["A","B"],"relation_id":["7","9"]}}};

  $.each(mockJSON.json_list, function (i, n){
    if(Array.isArray(n.funding_project_name)) {
      $.each(n.funding_project_name, function (i2, p){
        dt.row.add([n.firstname,'<a href="/'+ n.relation_id[i2] +'">' + p + '</a>']);
        dt.draw(false);
      });
    } else {
      dt.row.add([n.firstname,  '<a href="/"' + n.relation_id + '"">' + n.funding_project_name + '</a>']);
      dt.draw(false);
    }
  });
}
```

Like previously stated, there may be some built in functions to handle this that I am unaware but when things get complicated, just know you can take manual control of it.

Full Example:

```js
var dt;

    $(document).ready(function () {
      dt = $('#empTable').DataTable();
      loadDT();
    });

    function loadDT(){
      var mockJSON = { "json_list":{  "125":{  "firstname":"John","funding_project_name":"A","relation_id": "7"},"133":{  "firstname":"Cesar","funding_project_name":["A","B"],"relation_id":["7","9"]}}};
      $.each(mockJSON.json_list, function (i, n){
         var projLinks = "";
        if(Array.isArray(n.funding_project_name)) {
          $.each(n.funding_project_name, function (i2, p){
          projLinks += '<a href="/'+ n.relation_id[i2] +'">' + p + '</a> ';
          });
        } else {
          projLinks = '<a href="/"' + n.relation_id + '"">' + n.funding_project_name + '</a>';
        }
        dt.row.add([n.firstname, projLinks]);
        dt.draw(false);
      });
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="empTable">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>First Name</th><th>ProjectName</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Could be a solution of course, but all the source code must be turned upside down

Comment: This will create n rows for each funding. The idea is create always one row, where the column of fundings can have n entries.

Comment: @anvd Ok, then just build up a variable to contain your list of links inside your iteration then add the row post logic. See modified code snippet.